# Why std::get<T> where T is the result of call a constexpr function fails?

Tags: c++, c++17

My ask is about how is this code actually working:

```
std::variant<int, std::string> is;
constexpr int i = 0;
std::cout << std::get<i>(is);
```

And now if I write the following code its fails:

```
std::variant<int, std::string> is;
std::cout << std::get<is.index()>(is);
```

In documentation https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/index i'd found that the return type of index is `constexpr`.
Can someone help me with this?

## Update

Now by using std::string_view instead of std::string which one can be constexpr too and making `is` also constexpr. It works. Thanks

Comment: But 'is' is not constexpr, so is.index() is not constant expression.

Comment: `constexpr` is not part of the (return) type. It is a specifier on the function or variable declaration.

Comment: I want to do something like the boost::variant implentation in that one 'is' can be auto-cast to the type needed whitout unwrap it by using std::get

Comment: @Are you talking specifically about the code example [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html#variant.tutorial.basic) containing the line `std::cout << v << std::endl;`? That works because boost overloads `operator<<` for the variant, not because of some magic casting depending on the stored type.

Comment: You say that it works now with `string_view`, but that can only be true if you made `is` also `constexpr`, in which case `is` will become immutable. With a mutable `is` it won't work with `string_view` either.

Comment: Oh that makes sense haha. That's why I can't find the boost::variant::operator T().

Comment: Technically, the standard doesn't specify when `index()` is required to return a constant expression. Theoretically, the library implementer could, say, write `index()` such that it's only a constant expression when the variant has 1 type, and otherwise is not. It would be silly, but the standard seems to allow it. So basically, you can never count on `index()` being usable as a template argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `constexpr` method can return a `constexpr` value if invoked from a `constexpr` value.

So you have to define `is` as `constexpr`

```
 constexpr std::variant<int, std::string> is;
```

Unfortunately a `std::variant` can't be declared `constexpr` when if isn't a literal type, so when one of it's types, as `std::string`, isn't literal.

But works, by example

```
 constexpr std::variant<int, long> is;
```

Answer (score 0):

Template parameter values must be known at compile-time.

```cpp
std::variant<int, std::string> is;
constexpr int i = 0;
std::cout << std::get<i>(is);
```

This works because the value of `i` is declared with `constexpr` and thus is known at compile-time, so you are effectively calling `std::get<0>(is)`.

```cpp
std::variant<int, std::string> is;
std::cout << std::get<is.index()>(is);
```

This fails because `is` is not declared with `constexpr` and thus the value that `is.index()` returns cannot be known until run-time, so it cannot be used in a template parameter.